# Time it will take to crack a password file?

Tags: hash, password-cracking, salt

I'm trying to answer a multiple-choice question which is the following:

> "Consider the security of a password file, which includes a 10 bit
> salt and all passwords are hashed, but known to consist of exactly 8
> characters from the following alphabet:
>
> - lowercase letters ('a' to 'z')
> - uppercase letters ('A' to 'Z')
> - digits ('0' to '9')
> - the special characters (`.`, `-`, `_`, `+`, `<`, `>`, `=`, `@`).
>
> Assume that a password cracking system, which is able to check 12
> billion (10^12) guesses per second and is able to run around the clock
> all year, is used to crack the password file. Which of the following
> worst case estimates for cracking the password file is most accurate?"

The answer is Two years.

What I did is, I would say since the salts are fixed and there are 70 (26+26+10+8) characters for each bit and the password consists of 8bits-> 70^8 possible combinations. And this answer divided by the 12*10^12, but this gives me 48.04 seconds ? [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=70%5E8%20%2F%20%2812*10%5E12%29)

Comment: As the other question explains, this is not a security question but a maths question.

Comment: Are the salts known or in the password file? Each password should have its own salt. A character is not a bit. 10^12 is a trillion, not a billion. And you do not include *how many passwords there are*. So, all-in-all, this question is missing information and is a pure maths question.

Comment: Where is this question from?